# undefined method `text?' for nil:NilClass Validate uniqness rails3 ruby 187

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just updated from rails 2.3 to 3, i'm trying to replace this old method with something cleaner, because it's outputting the model and field name, wtf!

[image]

However I get the above error when calling **validates_uniqueness_of** (the presence works fine).  I passed in the primary id scope, and still get it.  Any help is welcome.

```
   def validate
     if org_name.blank?
       errors.add(:org_name, :blank, :default => nil)
     else
       if (org = Organization.find_by_org_name(org_name)) && org != self
         errors.add(:org_name, :taken, :default => nil, :value => org_name)
       end
     end
   end
```

to

```
validates :org_name, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :org_name, :scope => :org_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Ths is the Rails 3 syntax for uniqueness validtion:

validates :org_name, uniqueness:  {scope: :org_id}

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to fix.

Firstly, analyse the error message:

> Org name translation missing: 
>   en.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.org_name.blank

This is caused by the following line of code:

```
errors.add(:org_name, :blank, :default => nil)
```

When you call the above, you are telling rails to look for a translation whose key is `:blank`. You probably didn't set that up yet, so to do that, just go into your locales file (config/locales/en.yml), and add the following:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        organization:
          attributes:
            org_name:
              blank: "can't be blank."
```

Hopefully that will fix it for you.